# How to close activity, so cannot be opened again from active apps?

Tags: android, android-activity

i have custom activity which is called from background by receiver.

After on button click i want to close activity, so cannot be opened again if user holds menu button and list of active apps is displayed.

How can i do it? I tried use finish() method and kill process, but without luck..i can always display activity from list of apps again.

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

I Just added

```
<activity android:noHistory="true"
```

But after finish the activity i am able to get back into the activity (See image below).

Activity is started from receiver with following flags (maybe problem is here?)

```
intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:noHistory="true"` and in AndroidMainfest

Answer (score 1):

just add `android:noHistory="true"` to the activity manifest.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

> android:noHistory
>   Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be finished, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".
>   A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.
>
> This attribute was introduced in API Level 3.

Comment: After android:noHistory="true" i'm still able to get back into app after finish(). I updated question..

Comment: I saw your update. Not sure, when I used this flag was spot-on. Yeah, maybe remove some of those flags.